# Get the size of firebase cache

Tags: android, firebase, caching, firebase-realtime-database, persistence

I enabled firebase persistence in my app

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

while firebase store data in local storage as a database, there is a way to get the size of this database? Cause I want to check if firebase has something in cache or not yet?

I tried with

```
        File cacheDir = this.getCacheDir();
```

and get the size of this file but it always get 0 even firebase have cache or not.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to know the size of the cache managed internally by the Firebase client SDK.  But the maximum size of the cache is mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-prioritizing-the-local-cache):

> By default, 10MB of previously synced data is cached. This should be
>   enough for most applications. If the cache outgrows its configured
>   size, the Firebase Realtime Database purges data that has been used
>   least recently. Data that is kept in sync is not purged from the
>   cache.

`getCacheDir` is a method provided by Android to give you the location of the folder where individual apps may store cache data.  That could include any data from any part of the app.